# User Profile Application without Sync - SharePoint 2013

Tags: user-profile, active-directory, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

I would like to know how does SharePoint map the attribute ***PreferredName*** when no sync from AD is effective ?

I'm having issues after having provisioned the user profile service application but didn't set any sync with AD (which is intended) : the ***PreferredName*** isn't mapped with the ***DisplayName*** attribute from Active Directory so users see their `domain\username` where `username` is not filled with **Name Surname** but instead with an ID.

Edit: There is 2 separate domains, one for the servers and one that is storing the user database, could it be that there is no trust relation between the 2 domains so my users are able to connect to SharePoint but the user profile isn't able to retrieve user informations from the Active Directory ?

Any help is welcomed.

Second edit :

- Before setting up UPS : How does SharePoint get the DisplayName of the user when the user connects to a site collection if not getting from AD ? It needs it to display the name and surname of the user in SharePoint and stores it in UIL (User Information List)
- After setting up UPS with no sync from AD : same question as above ? When I log into CA and I display all user profiles, I can see their "account name" and their "PreferredName", but the "PreferredName" isn't correctly filled with the DisplayName attribute of AD.

When a user is connecting to a new site collection after having set up the UPS, it is showing his account name as his identity in the upper right corner of SharePoint UI.

When I display his user profile in UPS, only the account name is filled.

Before I set up UPS and on the site collection that were created before setting it up, my users were seeing (or able to see) their "Name Surname" in the upper right corner of SharePoint UI.

I need to know how can I fix this issue and fill their "PreferredName" property with their DisplayName AD attribute.

Comment: Are you talking about to update user profile manually in SharePoint?

Comment: I want to know why the DisplayName AD attribute isn't mapped with the PreferredName.

Comment: PreferredName has already mapped with AD display name in User profile property.